# Ackerman Recursividad

Tags: java

Intento escribir una solución recursiva que calcule la función de Ackerman:

Para los valores de `m` y `n` dados, la función de Ackerman se describe del siguiente modo :

```
A(m,n) = n+1 ,             si m = 0
A(m,n) = A(m-1,1) ,        si n = 0
A(m,n) = A(m-1,A(m,n-1)) , si m > 0  y  n > 0
```

El código que implementé es el siguiente, aunque me da un stack over flow

```
public class Ackeman{
    public int ackerman(int m, int n){
        int acker = 0;
        if(m==0){
            acker += n+1;
        }else{
            if(n == 0){
                acker += ackerman(m-1,1);
            }else if(m > 0 && n > 0){
                acker += ackerman(m-1,ackerman(m,n-1));
            }
        }
        return acker;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: el stack over flow pues aun soy aprendiz de la programacion]

aun no se como funcionan sus formatos ya me ire acostumbrando y gracias a mariano por editarlo y que se vea mas presentable el ide se llama blue j y pues nada no se como cerrar el tema la cuestion es que si funciona el codigo y el stack over flow se debe a que introduci valores muy altos eh aqui un concepto de wikipedia funcion ackerman :
"Para darse una idea de la magnitud de los valores que aparecen de la fila 4 en adelante, se puede destacar que por ejemplo, A(4, 2) es mayor que el número de partículas que forman el universo elevado a la potencia 200 y el resultado de A(5, 2) no se puede escribir dado que no cabría en el Universo físico. En general, por debajo de la fila 4, ya no es posible escribir todos los dígitos del resultado de la función."

Comment: Al final siempre te va a salir esa excepción por el crecimiento tan brutal que tiene esa función, pero está bien hecha porque puedes ver la salida como va subiendo como debe ser. Debes poner un límite en la profundidad o un valor máximo para dejar la recursividad o siempre morirá en esa excepción.

Comment: muy cierto almenos podria poner en condiciones de contexto o simplemente poner una restriccion para m<=5 y para n <=2 gracias

Answer (score 1):

Yo lo he probado y veo que va bien. Si añades antes de `return acker` esta línea verás que está calculando todo como dices:

```
System.out.println(acker);
```

Comment: Por imprimir algo no va a solucionarse el desbordamiento de pila.

Comment: @ArtEze Claro que no, era sólo para que el OP viera que funciona bien. El desbordamiento lo evitará con lo que le he dicho antes, poniendo un máximo de profundidad en sus llamadas recursivas o un valor máximo antes de que se desborde.